# jquery no conflict error is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery no conflict, but without success. **I have deliberately included jquery twice in the page for testing purposes to get an error!** I know jquery should only be included once, but the point is to try to make it bulletproof against poorly coded themes out there.

Here is the test case:

https://jsfiddle.net/v2jupagc/

If I include second jquery link after my JavaScript code block I get an error. How can I make no conflict work with my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function($) {
            $.fn.test = function(){console.log('1')}
        })(jQuery);

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

         if (!/loaded|interactive|complete/.test(document.readyState)) document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",onLoad); else onLoad();  
        function onLoad() {    
            var nc = jQuery;     
            nc.noConflict();
            nc("#wrapper").test();
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current logic doesn't work because you overwrite the `$` (which you added the `$.test()` logic to) with the next reference to jQuery 3.3.1.

You need to call `$.noConflict()` on the *first* version of jQuery that you load so that you retain a reference to it. Something like this, although note that `nc` is now a reference to jQuery 1.12.4:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var nc = $.noConflict();
    
  (function($) {
    $.fn.test = function() {
      console.log('1')
    }
  })(nc);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (!/loaded|interactive|complete/.test(document.readyState)) 
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad);
  else 
    onLoad();

  function onLoad() {
    nc("#wrapper").test();
  }
  
  // just to illustrate the point
  console.log('nc =', nc.fn.jquery);
  console.log('jQuery =', jQuery.fn.jquery);
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way this can be done so I dont specify nc in })(nc); ? so it leaves jQuery })(jQuery);

Comment: Yes, you could just use `jQuery` there instead, I used `nc` for clarity on which version will be used within that block.